# Android:Log-in with facebook

Tags: android, facebook

If i want to log in with facebook in my android app, it tells me: App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permission.

I have fallowed step by step this tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login.

In facebook.developers i have put my app in LIVE mode and added Contact email.
I am admin also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is facebook bug dude, it is better if you create new apps and start over.